# I want to add delay between two statements in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

My Code looks like this:

```
// this statement is deleting enteries from table
 object.CleanTables();
// this statement is getting count of enteries in table
var count= object.getCount();
expect(count).toBe(1);
```

Count value returned is incorrect because there is no delay between fetching count statement and cleaning database tables.
How can i add delay between these two statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the ultimate goal of your code is, given that you have provided very little context. But if you need to add a delay between these statements, you can add a setTimeOut() function which will in turn trigger the getCount() method.

Something like this should 'add a delay' :

```
object.cleanTables();
var count= object.getCount();
setTimeout(() => {
    expect(count).toBe(1);
}, 2000);
```

The above mentioned code within the curly braces of setTimeout function will execute after 2000ms i.e. 2 seconds.

Hope this helps!